# Hourly forecast

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to forecast hourly Oil prediction based on each product. The data is from 04-01-2018 to 14-01-2020. I used frequency 24.The problem is that data is irregular like some days are missing due to sensor error. I used ARIMA model but result are not satisfactory. The model is Reading and forecasting monthly. Whereas I need hourly forecast. Any suggestion

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hourly predictions MAY depend on anthropormorphic activity

These might include

what day of the week it is

what month your are in

what level changes have occurred

what trend changes have occurred

what days of the month exhibit statistically usual effect

what recent activity has been *arima structure"

what week of the month you are in

holiday effects before, on and after

long weekend effects

EDITED AFTER @Whuber's question about replacement values .

As a small example consider a time series containing 10 values

1,9,1,9,1,9,1,9,na,9

and we wish to estimate the missing value at time period 9 .

We initially set (without loss of generalization) the missing value to 0 .

We form a useful model which suggests an anomaly at time period 9 suggesting that the observed value (0) was 1 less than what id should have been thus the replacement value is a +1 .

The model is here

[image] and here [image] . The suggest adjustment to the initial value of 0.0 is the complement of the estimated intervention effect (+1)

[image]

Essentially the arima structure provides a clue to the recursive process thus exposing/highlighting the size of the "unusual values".

Comment: How does this address the stated problem of *missing data?*

Comment: yes .. they can interpolate to obtain estimates of missing values or intervention detection to estimate pulses which is in essence estimating missing values

Comment: Thank you! (+1)